# Issue on OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have a Class called `Captcha.php` like :

```
<?php
class Captcha {
     const FIRST_NUM   = 1;
     const SECOND_NUM  = 9;

    private $num1 = rand(FIRST_NUM,SECOND_NUM);
    private $num2 = rand(FIRST_NUM,SECOND_NUM);

    function CreatNums(){
        return $num1;
    }
}
```

In index.php I tried to instantiate the class like

```
<?php
include_once('Captcha.php');
$tat = new Captcha();
$result = $tat->CreatNums();
echo $result;
```

but it is not returning/ echoing any thing on the page. can you please let me know why this is happening?

Thansk

Comment: Enable `error_reporting` early on to see syntax errors.

Comment: Turn on error reporting.  http://3v4l.org/ZNWgf

Comment: For starters you typically can't set the default value of a property to the result of an expression. That needs to be done in a constuctor.

Comment: Jonatha's got it: your class is an outright syntax error, so PHP is bailing at the include() stage. Since you don't mention seeeing any errors, you've probably got error_reporting and display_errors off. Neither should EVER be off when developing or debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
class Captcha {
    const FIRST_NUM   = 1;
    const SECOND_NUM  = 9;

    private $num1; 
    private $num2;

    function __construct(){
        $this->num1 = rand(self::FIRST_NUM, self::SECOND_NUM);
        $this->num2 = rand(self::FIRST_NUM, self::SECOND_NUM);
    }

    function CreatNums(){
        return $this->num1;
    }
}

$tat = new Captcha();
$result = $tat->CreatNums();
echo $result;
```

Comment: To explain what is going on... You cannot set a default value of a class variable to a method call, this is because it needs to be computed while compiling (yes PHP compiles...) and `rand()` can only be run during "runtime". Therefore, since `__construct()` is executed during run time, we have the answer above...